# my laptop wifi LED is not working

Tags: wireless, asus

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 X64, my laptop is Asus X32U .
The WIFI connection is working good but the WIFI LED on the laptop is not working at all.
here is the *rfkill list* result

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

could anyone help me this?

Comment: Some, but not all wireless drivers permit turning the LED on, off or blink. In order to help, tell us about your wireless device: lspci -nn | grep 0280

Comment: sorry for wating so long , the result is  06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)  thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Please try a temporary driver parameter:

```
sudo modprobe -r ath9k
sudo modprobe ath9k blink=1
```

If it works as expected, make it persistent with:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
```

Add a single line:

```
options ath9k blink=1
```

Proofread, save and close gedit. You should be all set.

Comment: this is not working , its only shutdown the wifi and restart it ,the LED is still not on

Comment: I'm sorry, that's all that seems to be available in your driver ath9k.

Answer (score 0):

This does not work on my Asus K46 laptop, so I tried do dig.

```
lspci | grep -i wireless
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)

lspci -vv -s 02:00.0 
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
    Subsystem: AzureWave AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 17
    Region 0: Memory at f7d00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
    Expansion ROM at f7d80000 [disabled] [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k

modinfo ath9k | grep parm
parm:           debug:Debugging mask (uint)
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption (int)
parm:           blink:Enable LED blink on activity (int)
parm:           led_active_high:Invert LED polarity (int)
parm:           btcoex_enable:Enable wifi-BT coexistence (int)
parm:           bt_ant_diversity:Enable WLAN/BT RX antenna diversity (int)
parm:           ps_enable:Enable WLAN PowerSave (int)
parm:           use_chanctx:Enable channel context for concurrency (int)
parm:           use_msi:Use MSI instead of INTx if possible (int)
```

After found the parameters blink and led_active_high I tested both as follows (of course with `sudo su`):

```
modprobe -v -r ath9k
rmmod ath9k
rmmod mac80211
rmmod ath9k_common
rmmod ath9k_hw
rmmod ath
rmmod cfg80211

modprobe -v ath9k blink=1
insmod /lib/modules/4.15.0-15-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/4.15.0-15-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/4.15.0-15-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/4.15.0-15-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_hw.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/4.15.0-15-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_common.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/4.15.0-15-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k.ko blink=1

modprobe -v -r ath9k
rmmod ath9k
rmmod mac80211
rmmod ath9k_common
rmmod ath9k_hw
rmmod ath
rmmod cfg80211

modprobe -v ath9k led_active_high=1
insmod /lib/modules/4.15.0-15-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/4.15.0-15-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/4.15.0-15-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/4.15.0-15-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_hw.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/4.15.0-15-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_common.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/4.15.0-15-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k.ko led_active_high=1
```

.. and the wifi LED is still off (but curiously works on other operating systems).